# Crash interacting with NSUserDefaults and NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` in which I am adding objective and storing in user defaults, but while adding it is crashing.

```
 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bssidObserverArray"]) {
        bssidObserverArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bssidObserverArray"];
    }

   if (bssidObserverArray.count > 0) {
        if (![bssidObserverArray containsObject:vendorID]) {
            NSLog(@"bssidObserverArray %@",bssidObserverArray);
            // In this line app is getting crashed
                [bssidObserverArray addObject:vendorID];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bssidObserverArray forKey:@"bssidObserverArray"];

        }
    }else{
        [bssidObserverArray addObject:vendorID];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bssidObserverArray forKey:@"bssidObserverArray"];
    }
```

Any suggestions would be more helpful.

Comment: To store an array you need to archive it first and then store in UserDefaults. Also need to unarchive  while retrieving that array.

Comment: @AshishGupta You only need to archive/unarchive the array if it contains non-property list values.

Comment: @zack Show the complete error message shown in the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `bssidObserverArray` is NSMutable array then come the problem here .

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bssidObserverArray"]) {
        bssidObserverArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bssidObserverArray"];
    }
```

since NSUserdefaults returns immutable. you can do like this

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bssidObserverArray"]) {
        NSArray *someArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bssidObserverArray"];
        bssidObserverArray = [someArray mutableCopy];

    }
```